# How to pass non-string objects between routes in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I am building a file viewer. For this, I have a component called `FileBrowserComponent` which is displayed when the route is called `/files`.

I attach a query param when navigating in order to display the content of a directory. So to open a specific directory, I call [Router.navigate](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigate) with `/files?location=c:/users/xyz/...'.

Inside the component, I subscribe to `ActivatedRoute.queryParam`, which means whenever the component is active I get notified when the user browses to another location and I can then display the files and folders.

In one case I need to pass an optional non-string object to the URL. But I subscribe only to the `queryParams` object that gives me the Params as a string.

What other object can I subscribe to, that triggers a callback whenever I navigate to that route that gives me back the query params including the custom object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, consider passing the id and then regetting the object from a remote endpoint.

If that is something that can't be applied to your situation then create a subject that holds the state:

(note this is a const that is declared outside of a class)

```
export const someRouteParams$ = new BehaviorSubject<YourObjectTypeHere>({...your defaults here });
```

For which you later send the object that you want to pass:

```
someRouteParams$.next({ ...your passed object });
```

and eventually subscribe in your sub component:

```
someRouteParams$.subscribe(someObject => {
    console.log(someObject);
});
```

Alternatively, get a state management library like NGXS, Akita or NGRX to manage this state for you